# Jasmine is failing on console.error test, before previous async test is done

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

In my test sweet I have these two tests. One is async, the other tests console.error. I have Jasmine as ^2.5.3, and testing on chrome 44.0.2403.

The first test looks like so

```
describe('Async test', function() {
    const config = {'foo':'bar'};
    let $rootScope = false;
    beforeEach( module('my.lovely.async') );
    function createService( config ) {
        let createdService = false;
        module( $provide => $provide.constant("config", config);
        inject( ( $injector, _$rootScope_ ) => {
            createdService = $injector.get("MyAsyncService");
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        })
        return createdService;
    }
    it("should do async stuff", done => {
        createService(config).doAsync().then( data => {
            expect(data.awesome).toContain("foo"); // <=== ref point 1
        });
        $rootScope.$digest();
        done()
    });
});
```

This runs just fine on it's own.

Then the next test is:

```
describe('console.error test', function() {

    let DebugService = false;
    beforeEach( function(){
        module('my.app');
        module('my.debug.module');
        inject( ( $injector, _$rootScope_ ) => {
            DebugService = $injector.get("DebugService");
            $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        })
    });

    it("should log errors", function() {
        spyOn(console, "error").and.callThrough();
        console.error("Banana"); // <=== ref point 2
        expect(DebugService.getErrors()).toContain("Banana")
    });
});
```

In my `app.module('my.app').config(....).run(...)` code, the run block overrides the `console.error` call so that it also goes to `DebugService.error`. A snippet is here:

```
App.run(['DebugService', function(DebugService){
    var consoleError = console.error;
    console.error = function (message) {
        consoleError.call(console, message);
        DebugService.error(message);
    };
})
```

What I'm seeing is that, when karma gets to to `ref point 1` in the first test, pressing the 'step over' button ends up at the `ref point 2` in the second, then after that I get to the `module.$$afterEach` function in ngMocks. Jumping ahead to `module.$$cleanUp` it looks like I'm already in the second test.

I can't tell if the first test hasn't done it's async stuff right, or if the second test's console.error is failing the test.

How do I get both tests to run?

Comment: I've tried moving the `done` inside the `then` call, and it just fails the first test as well.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly the problem is since you didn't provide error messages or so. What exactly is 'failing'? You haven't provided MyAsyncService, which is relevant here. The first test is probably NOT asynchronous and shouldn't have `done` in the first place (if it is, it surely should have `done` inside `then`).

Comment: @estus it returns a promise whic doesn't resolve straight away. I'm reworking the test to use `$httpBackend`. Once I've done that I'll update the question. As it stands test 1 is not working in it's current state.